# Deleting part of a result

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following

```
$html   .= '<option value="' . $option['id'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . JText::_( $option['name'] ) . '</option>';
```

Which displays data from the db and populates a drop down list.

```
eg data 
My name is John
My name is Jim
My name is Jason
My name is Julie
```

What I would like to do is remove "My name is" from each result so the list is just the names.

I have tried the following

```
JText::_( substr($option['name'],strlen('my name is ')) ) . '</option>';
```

Which works by deletingg the first 11 characters, however, some entries in the list do not have the "My Name is" and so this deletes the name too.

I cant seem to find something that allows me to define the expression i want to delete.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you always assume that it's the last word in the line that contains the name you want to replace? Or can it be e.g. My name is John Doe, and you want to display "John Doe" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$html   .= '<option value="' . $option['id'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . 
    JText::_( str_replace("My name is ", "", $option['name']) ) . 
    '</option>';
```

This replaces any occurrences of "My name is " by an empty string. If the search string is not present, it will just do nothing.

Comment: This does not solve the case where the OP says the entry does NOT always contain "My name is"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name to fetch is always one word and always at the end of the string, the following should return the name only:

```
JText::_( substr($option['name'], strrpos($option['name'], ' ') ) ). '</option>';
```

What we do is simply search for the last occurrence of a space character using strrpos and return everything after that using substr.